# panda dataframe: persisting a list of numbers and then reading it

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe that contains a list of numbers (positive and negative numbers). I persist the dataframe to a csv, and when I read it the list of numbers is a string. And it's difficult to convert it back to a list: python complains about the square brackets and the minus sign. Is there a way of persisting lists of numbers and reading them back as list of numbers?

```
data = [['tom', [10,-5,3]], ['dave', [15,-1,4]], ['al', [14,-1,-1]]] 
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Name', 'Points']) 
df1.to_csv("points.csv")
df2 = pd.read_csv("points.csv")
```

The points column in df2 is a string. How to converti it to a list of numbers?

Comment: post a mimumn code of what you are trying to do

Comment: how about using `json` instead? it will let you keep `int` value type.

Comment: This is far too unclear.

Comment: You're storing your data as a Python list inside a dataframe, that's not very pandas-friendly and when you `read_csv` back in, it reads your `Points` integer values as string. Better to store your numbers as individual rows in the dataframe. Are all the lists guaranteed to have length 3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use pickle here with [`DataFrame.to_pickle`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_pickle.html) and [`read_pickle`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_pickle.html), because csv data are always strings:

```
data = [['tom', [10,-5,3]], ['dave', [15,-1,4]], ['al', [14,-1,-1]]] 
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Name', 'Points']) 

df1.to_pickle("points.pkl")
df2 = pd.read_pickle("points.pkl")
print (type(df2.loc[0, 'Points']))
<class 'list'>
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't store your data as a Python list inside a pandas dataframe, that's going to be a pain to write out as CSV and read back, the types will get mangled (unless you use pickle, or JSON, which you can, but why unnecessarily create complications?).

Easier to **simply store as a native pandas dataframe**:

```
df3 = pd.DataFrame({'tom': [10,-5,3], 'dave': [15,-1,4], 'al': [14,-1,-1]})

df3
   tom  dave  al
0   10    15  14
1   -5    -1  -1
2    3     4  -1

df3.to_csv('my.csv', index=False)

# Now when we read it back in, the integer columns remain integer...
df3in = pd.read_csv('my.csv')

   tom  dave  al
0   10    15  14
1   -5    -1  -1
2    3     4  -1

df3.info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 3 entries, 0 to 2
Data columns (total 3 columns):
tom     3 non-null int64
dave    3 non-null int64
al      3 non-null int64
dtypes: int64(3)
memory usage: 152.0 bytes
```